# How request microphone access in html5

Tags: javascript, html

i have code like this

```
function initAudio() {
    if (!navigator.webkitGetUserMedia)
        return(alert("Error: getUserMedia not supported!"));

    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio:true}, gotStream, function(e) {
            alert('Error getting audio');
            console.log(e);
        });
}

window.addEventListener('load', initAudio );
```

my output in console is this

```
NavigatorUserMediaError {code: 1, PERMISSION_DENIED: 1}
```

why permission deny for me?
I try to make audio recorder from source code of this page http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html

Comment: Are you running this locally or on a server

Comment: But you explicitly gave it the permission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your running your code from a file saved on your machine not through a web server, chrome sometimes has issues with allowing access due to its secuirty policy.

Two options to try are

1. Putting it on a web server
2. Opening chrome through terminal using the command below if you are on mac

   /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files

Comment: The second option does not work anymore. See here on how to set up a simple server in one line: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19292612/2293095. Then access your "index.html" by opening up a browser and accessing this site in http://127.0.0.1:8000/