# HTML5 Web Speech API not working locally

Tags: javascript, html, speech-recognition, speech-synthesis

I am trying to make this code work and don't know why is it not working locally. I tried the same on CodePen.io and it works.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Voice API</title>

</head>

<body>
    <button onClick="func()">Click Me</button>
    <script>
        function func()
        {
            alert('Hello');
            var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
            recognition.continuous = true;
            recognition.interimResults = true;
            recognition.onresult = function(event) 
            { 
                alert(event.results[0][0].transcript); 
            }
            recognition.start();
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try adding the following snippet to see what error is being generated.

```
recognition.onerror = function(event) {
    console.log(event.error);
};
```

Chances are its spitting out a 'not-allowed' which generally means that the user agent is not allowing any speech input to occur for reasons of security, privacy or user preference (as you're running it locally through a file:// )

Have you tried serving the page under a local Web Server such as (IIS or Node) ?

Comment: Yes. That resulted in a 'not-allowed'. I used a local WAMP server and it worked.

Comment: You have an extra parenthesis at the end.

Comment: on server must be https on local must be localhost not https:// + localhost . Please check you mic for "not-allowed".

Comment: Mine works locally, but after deploying to AWS EC2, the microphone no longer works giving `speechRecognitionError - error: not allowed`. For the popup, I switch it back to `ask if ... wants to access your microphone`. Then as soon as I click to speak again, it turns the mic setting back to `continue blocking microphone access`

Comment: @Growler : Try using with SSL certificate on AWS and it will work. By default , its on http. You need to configure https.

Comment: @sw. if you see something like this (which I think is typo) you can edit to improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Detailed discussion why camera (and microphone are not working on localhost here):

[How to allow Chrome to access my camera on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835421/how-to-allow-chrome-to-access-my-camera-on-localhost)

In short, it is explicitly blocked.