# Can I use the SpeechRecognition API on localhost?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, speech-recognition

While integrating the [`SpeechRecognition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition) to a user interface, I always get `SpeechRecognitionError` events when trying to call the `.play()` method.

I have tried to allow the microphone, but it's always marked as blocked when I refresh the page, and I see no way to allow it.

Is there any way to test this API on localhost?

Also, why is it disabled locally in the first place?

Comment: in chrome if you click just left of the nav bar (the secure/insecure square) you should be able to click site settings and enable the mic from there

Comment: It's indicated as "Ask" for the microphone, but I still the error. And when I go in "Site settings", the choice is disabled, and set as "blocked".

Comment: Can anyone explain how a JavaScript expert would be useful here?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu if you consider yourself a "JavaScript export" and do not wish to answer, by all mean don't answer! But since JavaScript is used, here, the tag is set.

Comment: I was asking myself how [ask] applies here. If this question was asked by a fresh user, the question would have been closed as off-topic for 4 different reasons, with an average score of -7 by now. IMHO, high rep users should not act more "equal" than others.They should be setting an example. A good one, for that matter. On a different note, I'm afraid I didn't get your "export" joke. What did you mean?

Comment: [no-attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/), [no-code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/), [missing-exception-details](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/) & [no-research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/).

Comment: Also discussed before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481119/html5-web-speech-api-not-working-locally

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I have see that answer, and I already have the error event.... this how I know there's an error. No, the problem is that I cannot allow the mic at all on localhost.