# HTML5 Web Speech API not working on the local server

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, localhost

I am trying to make this code work and don't know why it is not working on my local server as well as on my hosting server. I tried the same locally and it works.

(
The curious thing is that there is a question here opposite to mine: [HTML5 Web Speech API not working locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481119/html5-web-speech-api-not-working-locally#)

Which makes it look even stranger.
)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Voice API</title>

</head>

<body>
<button 
onClick="func()">Click 
Me</button>
<script>
    function func()
    {
        alert('Hello');
        var recognition = 
new 
 webkitSpeechRecognition();

recognition.continuous = 
true;

recognition.interimResults = 
true;
        recognition.onresult 
= function(event) 
        { 
            alert(event. 
Hi[0][0].transcript); 
        }
        recognition.start();
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, It seems you are trying to use the speech API of google chrome, Please add google chrome tag to your question.

Comment: If there are errors in console, Add them to your question.

Comment: No error, dude.

Comment: Does the browser prompt for permission to use the microphone? Is the site https? I'm pretty sure the API will only work over SSL

Comment: No, it doesn't. As to the site I am not sure about https and it really doesn't have SSL. But why then the code doesn't work on the local server?