# Manage exceptions for camera and microphone in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to make an exception for a site to access my microphone and camera:

`chrome://settings/contentExceptions#media-stream` is not editable, is it normal?

How do I add a rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible as you would expect. [Reported as a bug here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=248987) and closed as **Status: WontFix**. Details below.

> ---
>
> #14 freshst...@renuval.com Version: Version 28.0.1500.95 m OS: Windows 7 64 bit
>
> We've read on an earlier Issue from 2011 that it's intended behavior
> as well, but some people on the same Issue weren't sure:
> https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=71179
>
> Chrome Help sites discuss the topic here:
>
> https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2693767?hl=en
>
> Note that the Media Exceptions page doesn't explicitly say that you
> can add exceptions, it only says you can deny. It does, however, point
> you to the Manage Exceptions page on this topic which does say that
> you can add using a button. This looks like it's just unintentionally
> misleading.
>
> After re-reading everything carefully, we assumed based on the help
> article that the only way to de facto *allow* an exception is to click
> "Allow" on a site requesting an exception *that is running on HTTPS*
> as Chrome will only remember your preference for Media Exceptions on
> HTTPS sites. It seems a bit restrictive for users who are savvy enough
> to edit their own security settings deep down in the menu tree, but
> security is security.
>
> ---
>
> #15 ser...@chromium.org
>
> Thank you freshstart. This is exactly it. Https
> means that "allow" can stick.

Your question was also already answered on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/854108/manage-exceptions-for-camera-and-microphone):

> You add a rule by going to the site in question and then, if Media
> setting is "Ask when a site wants to use a plug-in to access your
> computer", it should prompt you for what to do - that will then get
> set as a specific exception.
>
> You only use Manage Exceptions to remove existing exceptions.
>
> See
> [Allow sites to access your camera and microphone](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2693767?hl=en) and [Manage
> exceptions](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3123708?p=settings_manage_exceptions&rd=1)

[Another Stack Overflow answer had a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16929608/1085891), but it reportedly does not work any more. Via *[How to allow Chrome to access my camera on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835421/how-to-allow-chrome-to-access-my-camera-on-localhost)*.