# Allowing Camera and Mic access in Chrome 64

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I've read over this [promising thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067298/grant-access-to-video-and-audio-in-chrome-48-via-selenium-chromedriver-automatic?answertab=active#tab-top) to try and enable this, but the suggestions aren't working or I'm not following well enough.  I tried both methods spelled out in the previous link but no luck. There are no errors in the IDE and Chrome launches fine, but camera and mic still aren't allowed.(details below).

I should also mention that I'm not just trying to make the pop up go away, I need the camera and microphone for testing our application.

I'm using Java 8, Selenium Webdriver 3.8.1, Chrome v.64.

**Option 1**

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\64.0.3282.140\\default_apps\\1.4_0.crx"));
options.addArguments("start-maximized");

Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.content_settings.exceptions.media_stream_camera.'https://<oursite>:443,'.setting","1");
prefs.put("profile.content_settings.exceptions.media_stream_mic.'https://<oursite>:443,'.setting","1");
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Tools\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.get(<oursite>);
```

**Option 2**

```
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\<user>\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default");
```

Thanks for any help offered (especially if it works).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to automate \*\*Allow Camera\*\* pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007699/not-able-to-automate-allow-camera-pop-up)

Comment: The answer in that thread was to specify a fake camera, but I need to enable a real camera.  So I don't think it is a duplicate, though certainly the same root issue.

Comment: Then again, once I actually used the "fake-ui" argument it actually made my real camera start working...  so that appears to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end, it was a very simple 'fix' to make it work for me.  The "use-fake-ui-for-media-stream" argument turned on the real camera and mic.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream");

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Tools\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.get(<oursite>);
```

Comment: And what about Firefox?

Answer (score 4):

Allowing Camera using add argument `use-fake-ui-for-media-stream`

```
ChromeOptions optionsC = new ChromeOptions();
optionsC.addArguments(Arrays.asList("disable-infobars", "ignore-certificate-errors", "start-maximized","use-fake-ui-for-media-stream"));
```