# Webcam.js not working in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, webcam, webcam.js

I am implementing webcam.js in my website.
I have downloaded script https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs This script is working fine in mozilla firefox browser. But Not working in google chrome.
Please check below link

http://beta.phygee.com/webcam-to-gif

[image]

Please Let me know what is error with my code :(

Comment: You need to use an https connection, see this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27282973/3461463

Answer (score 0):

this is because in google crome you are not allowed to use webcam js in http for this you have to use proper ssl or you can use other browser like firefox or you can call it in i frame

Answer (score 0):

Access your website using https instead of just http