# how to allow microphone for local ip in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, arduino-uno, webspeech-api

I am hosting my page inside the sdcard of arduino, I have implemented web speech api feature in that, however when I test my site using `127.0.0.1/project-X` , everything works perfect, but when I use `192.168.1.4`(which is same machine) or `192.168.1.10` (which is other laptop having WAMP) Chrome does not allow the microphone? I have also tried to start Chrome using different flags found on Google but none of them worked. What to do? I just want Chrome to allow using microphone from local ip also!

Comment: Localhost means localhost (127.0.0.1), and not any other host name or address.

Comment: yes,i know that ! i just prefer to use the 127.0.0.1

Comment: camera and mic security are the same. You could look at this answer for little more info. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835421/how-to-allow-chrome-to-access-my-camera-on-localhost

Answer (score 1):

Chrome now allows Microphone access over secured Http only. You can very easily create your own signed SSL certificate and use that to host your page via Https.In tomcat server.xml you just have to un-comment the ssl connector and point to the location of your certificate.