# How to temporarily allow insecure origins on mobile while developing website?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, ssl

Problem....

I'm making a web app that requires webcam access.

It works over localhost.

But I try to access it through mobile because it has camera and website if mobile first.

To access I type local ip address.

Website load, but gives error that it's insecure so can't load camera.

I could reconfigure and generate my own ssl keys. But it'd still be invalid certificate in mobile.

Comment: refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835421/how-to-allow-chrome-to-access-my-camera-on-localhost

Comment: which answer are you referring to, top one says host it locally so you won't have to use file protocol. which is not the problem i've