# Speech recognition provide an unknown error after listening

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition

I have a `templates / index.html` file. When you click on the first button, `btn_query`, you should call`startDictation()`, a javascript function for speech recognition. But there is a problem, which only appears on StackOverflow and with Chrome, with `recognition.onresult = function (e) {...}`.

1. I do not get the pop-up `window.alert (5 + 6);` at the beginning of the function.

2. The StackOverflow console recognizes that there is an error and writes: `Recognition had an error`. But I do not know which one.

It acts like this: it asks for the permission to use the microphone and then there is a red light on the tab on the top and finally the error message.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="margin: auto; display:table;">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script>var synth = window.speechSynthesis;</script>
    <!-- HTML5 Speech Recognition API -->
    <script>
            function startDictation() {
                document.getElementById('transcript').value = '';
                document.getElementById('output').value = '';
                if (window.hasOwnProperty('webkitSpeechRecognition')) {
                    var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
                    recognition.continuous = false;
                    recognition.interimResults = false;
                    recognition.lang = "en-US";
                    recognition.start();
                    recognition.onresult = function (e) {
                        window.alert(5 + 6);
                        document.getElementById('loader').hidden = false;
                        document.getElementById('transcript').value = e.results[0][0].transcript;
                        recognition.stop();
                        var data = e.results[0][0].transcript;
                        $.post("http://localhost:5000/news_urls", { "data": data },
                        function (response) {
                        document.getElementById('loader').hidden = true;
                            data = response;
                            document.getElementById("output").value = data["urls"];
                        }).error(function (response) {
                        document.getElementById('loader').hidden = true;
                            if (response.status == 400)
                                text = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText)["original_exception"];
                            else
                                text = "I'm sorry. I did not get that.";
                            document.getElementById("output").value = text;
                        });
                    };
                    recognition.onerror = function (e) {
                        recognition.stop();
                        console.log("Recognition had an error");
                        window.alert(10 + 6);
                    }
                }
            }

            function btnClick() {
                 synth.cancel();
                    var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(document.getElementById("output").value);
                    utterThis.voice = synth.getVoices()[0];
                    utterThis.pitch = 1.0;
                    utterThis.rate = 0.8;
                    utterThis.onerror = function(e) { console.log("Something went wrong with utterance."); };
                    synth.speak(utterThis);
            }
    </script>
    <style>
        .speech {
            border: 0px solid #DDD;
            width: 600px;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: "Calibri";
        }

            .speech input {
                border: 1;
                width: 240px;
                display: inline-block;
                height: 30px;
            }

            .speech img {
                float: right;
                width: 40px;
            }
    </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#e2e2e2">
    <h1 style="font-family: Calibri;">Delbot</h1>
    <div class="speech" ><i>It understands your voice commands, searches news and knowledge sources, and summarizes and reads out content to you.</i></div>
    <br /><i class="speech"><font color="gray">Only tested on Windows PCs. Not tested on other PCs or mobile devices.</font></i>

    <div class="speech">
            <textarea style="width: 600px;font-family: Calibri;font-size:x-large" name="q" id="transcript"
                      placeholder="Your query will appear here after you speak." rows="2" readonly="True"></textarea>
            <br>
            <input id="btn_query" type="button" onclick="startDictation()" value="Query"
                   style="font-family: Calibri;" />
            <img src="static/loader.gif" width="100px" align="left" style="float: left" hidden="True" id="loader" />
            <br><br>
            <h2 class="speech">Results</h2>
            <textarea style="width: 600px;font-family: Calibri;font-size:x-large" id="output" rows="2" placeholder="Results will appear here."
                      readonly="True"></textarea>
            <input id="btn_speak" type="button" value="Speak" onclick="btnClick()" style="font-family: Calibri;" />

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are running into the browser with a local file path.

> For e.g. `file://xyz/ss/ss/test.html`

Try to host this HTML file on the server and check you will get the appropriate result.

> Check [this](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/mXDTXrGRIBg) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835421/how-to-allow-chrome-to-access-my-camera-on-localhost). As chrome does not support to allow microphone with a local file path. You can forcefully do it but it is not recommended. With the really dangerous **--disable-web-security** (strongly not recommended, especially if you use this instance of Chrome for normal browsing as well, which can put your device in danger) and **--allow-file-access-from-files** (also not recommended).

**Debug:**

I am getting the same error by accessing the local file.
But while host the `index.html` file and access `http://localhost:1111` it's working perfectly.

[image]

**Note:-** Some editors load plain HTML into the browser. Try below editors where they host your file and run perfectly. Just C+V your code to an editor and run. Try with below editors.

1. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_javascript_editor.php
2. https://www.w3schools.com/tryit/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default

### Update=============

[image]

Comment: Yes ! My microphone wasn't set up as well :/

Comment: Yet, it seems to stop there. Do you know why I have no results? It may be a different question though.

Comment: So, have you `host` your file on server? Or still you are accessing directly HTML file in browser?

Comment: I hosted it on a localhost server

Comment: See, you should get alert `11` after you speak. `I have no results` I do not understand you. Your API does not return the result?

Comment: Ho, sorry, I meant results in the results area, that would handle back the answer of my question

Comment: @AliceAntoine , Check attached gif to the answer. It seems working perfectly. Maybe some minor quirks harassing you.

Comment: I have nothing changed to your code. And it seems working perfectly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176721/discussion-between-alice-antoine-and-hardik-shah).