# How to allow Chrome to access image on localhost from external http-page without compromising security?

Tags: image, google-chrome, http, localhost, private-network-access

Note that everything worked a few years (or months?) back.  However nowadays with Chrome 119 (I do not remember which version stopped working, sorry) it no more works, because Chrome apparently does no Preflight requests to `localhost`.

So I tried to find a solution with Google and on SO but only found questions, which are either unanswered or have no workable solution.  Hence I ask it here .. again .. in a way, which specifies the exact problem.

> Perhaps you are better in Googling than me?

These are the headers of the image from http://127.0.0.1:8080/:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: image/png
content-length: 3427
server: None
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-private-network: true
access-control-allow-headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
connection: close
```

`OPTIONS` for the same URL:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
server: None
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-private-network: true
access-control-allow-headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
connection: close
```

This is what Chrome tells me when the image is requested:

```
Access to image at 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/**REMOVED***' from origin 'http://**REMOVED**.i2p/**REMOVED**' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local`.
```

---

So the Question is:

**Is there a way to allow Chrome to display such images again?**

---

Notes:

The external page may be cached in a local proxy, such that everything works even when offline.  **This is not the primary, but a secondary requirement.**  As the external page is served via http this is easily possible.  Hence solutions which suggest to change the external page to `https` likely create more problems than they can solve.

> BTW the transport protocol is I2P in this example only.  The solution shall be applied to similar environments.  Keep in mind, that EEPsites do not support HTTPS, because LetsEncrypt does not support domains ending in `.i2p` .. yet.

The local and the external service shall not be changed, so it is likely, that solutions, which suggest that I change something drastically, cannot be adopted.

Using a local proxy which promotes HTTP to HTTPS such that Chrome stops complaining (and does Preflight requests) would involve a self signed certificate.  Self signed certificates are considered to be a security threat by me, because these must be added to the browser first, which is a manual thing.  And if done improperly things will get worse.  Also we shall never train normal people in installing some CA into the browser which then could possibly be abused as MitM!

### Things already considered

#### Extension

Adding some third party Extension to Chrome (like "Allow CORS") is a bad solution.  Extensions like these are good for debugging and development, but they are not good for the general use.  CORS rules are there for a good purpose.  It is wrong to get rid of CORS just to solve a "small" problem.

#### Dummy-Domain with Certificate variant 1

I could request a certificate for a dummy-domain with LetsEncrypt and publish this certificate such that it can be installed into a local webservice by everyone.  The HTTPS request to this dummy-domain then is intercepted by a local CONNECT proxy and forwarded, such that the external website looks like HTTPS.

> A bit like https://stackoverflow.com/a/77361023/490291

The problems here:

This only works for a single website.  Or things need to be rewritten into some cgiproxy-like fashion, which is error prone and may break easily.

#### Dummy-Domain with Certificate variant 2

The Dummy-Domain can also be used to access localhost.  Hence `localhost` suddenly appears to be coming from some Domain and not from IP 127.0.0.1.

For me this looks even worse:

The security of `localhost` suddenly depends on the security of the intercepting webservice.  Small bugs in the access policy might open a gaping hole which might be get abused by a third party.  Something I really do not want to do.  Using Preflight requests is simple and sound.  However AFAICS Chromes does not even try to use them.

As creating a wrapper is too dangerous, an option would be to integrate the wrapper into the webservice which serves the image.  Read:  Allow some localhost service to serve HTTPS under some Dummy-Domain.  But this then suddenly creates a dependency, which should not be there.  Also the solution should be, that this recipe can be applied to any webservice which is capable to set the correct CORS headers, not only a single one.

> Besides the I2P router this could be applied to things like CouchDB and other web enabled databases or caches.

#### Dummy-Domain general problems

The secret key of the certificate of the Dummy-Domain needs to be published (which automatically might trigger the invalidation of the certificate) and cannot be changed locally afterwards (as it is signed by LetsEncrypt).

> I won't create it the other way round, so I will never enable anybody to get a LetsEncrypt certificate on behalf of my Dummy-Domain (so everybody can keep the local secret key secret).

SSL certificates need to be updated on a regular basis, which creates unnecessary dependencies (to the dummy-domain used).  If the update fails, the problem suddenly arises again.

If you are offline longer than 3 months, everything breaks, because the locally used certificate becomes invalid.  This is very bad.

### Final thoughts

This all is not a problem as long as it only involves me alone.  However what I am looking for is a general solution, which can be deployed and adapted to a wide range of applications in the field of work.